# Sound stop playing

Tags: iphone, ios4, audio, ios5, avaudioplayer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone - Sound overlapping with multiple button presses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8101870/iphone-sound-overlapping-with-multiple-button-presses)

```
- (void)playOnce:(NSString *)aSound {

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:aSound ofType:@"caf"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    [theAudio setDelegate: self];
    [theAudio setNumberOfLoops:0];
    [theAudio setVolume:1.0];
    [theAudio play];



}

- (void)playLooped:(NSString *)aSound {

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:aSound ofType:@"caf"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    [theAudio setDelegate: self];
    // loop indefinitely
    [theAudio setNumberOfLoops:-1];
    [theAudio setVolume:1.0];
    [theAudio play];
    [theAudio release];

}
```

how do i make the sound stop playing when i press another button?