# Sound overlapping with multiple button presses

Tags: iphone, ios4, memory, audio

When I press a button, then press another one, the sounds overlap. How can I fix that so the first sound stops when another one is pressed?

```
 - (void)playOnce:(NSString *)aSound {

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:aSound ofType:@"caf"];
AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
[theAudio setDelegate: self];
[theAudio setNumberOfLoops:0];
[theAudio setVolume:1.0];
[theAudio play];    
 }

- (void)playLooped:(NSString *)aSound {

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:aSound ofType:@"caf"];
AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
[theAudio setDelegate: self];
// loop indefinitely
[theAudio setNumberOfLoops:-1];
[theAudio setVolume:1.0];
[theAudio play];
[theAudio release];


    }
```

Comment: You need to actually ask a question.

Comment: my question is that when i click on one button it plays sounds but then i click another one and they overlap

Comment: you can either do 1 of the following:  1.  when the button click, check if AVaudioplayer is still playing.  if yes you can ignore it and not do anything or 2 you can stop it then play the new sound.

Comment: - (void)playOnce:(NSString *)aSound;

Comment: - (IBAction) beatButton50 {
 
 [self playOnce:@"racecars"];
 
}

Comment: well.. try to remove the if(!theAudio) {} and check it out

Comment: if i remove the if(!theAudio) when i press multiple buttons the sound overlap

Comment: how many buttons you have? what do you exactly trying to achieve? i can't see how do you call all that void methods with 1 action. I know the best way to deal with sounds is in the delegate. Whats your purposes?

Comment: Stop posting the same question over and over. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100531 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8097525 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8096528 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8094557 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8101718/

Comment: Double-post of [Sound stop playing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8094557/sound-stop-playing)

Answer (score 0):

Declare your AVAudioPlayer in the header the viewController ( don't alloc a new one each time you play a sound). That way you will have a pointer you can use in a StopAudio method.

```
@interface myViewController : UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate> { 
    AVAudioPlayer *theAudio;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) AVAudioPlayer *theAudio;
@end


@implementation myViewController
@synthesize theAudio;
- (void)dealloc {
    [theAudio release];
}
@end



- (void)playOnce:(NSString *)aSound {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:aSound ofType:@"caf"];
    if(!theAudio){
        theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    }
    [theAudio setDelegate: self];
    [theAudio setNumberOfLoops:0];
    [theAudio setVolume:1.0];
    [theAudio play];
}

- (void)playLooped:(NSString *)aSound {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:aSound ofType:@"caf"];
    if(!theAudio){
        theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    }
    [theAudio setDelegate: self];
    // loop indefinitely
    [theAudio setNumberOfLoops:-1];
    [theAudio setVolume:1.0];
    [theAudio play];
}

- (void)stopAudio {
    [theAudio stop];
    [theAudio setCurrentTime:0];
}
```

also be sure to read the [Apple Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: how will i create the AVAudioPlayer in the header file i am new to this and don't know much

Comment: i added those line of codes and the sounds are still overlapping

Comment: just edited code above. can you describe what you are trying to achieve in more detail?

Comment: i am making an app that has like 20 buttons and each one plays a different sound but the sounds are overlapping when i click on other buttons

Comment: Then stop the AVAudioPlayer before playing the next sound.

Comment: for stopping the AVAudioPlayer do i just use the stop method

Comment: i used the code u gave me and when i click on a button it crashes the program

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do something like the following:

```
    (void) playLooped: (NSString * ) aSound {
        NSString * path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: aSound ofType: @"caf"];

    //stop audio player from playing so the sound don't overlap
    if([theAudio isPlaying])
    {
        [theAudio stop]; //try this instead of stopAudio

    }

    if (!theAudio) {
        theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL fileURLWithPath: path] error: NULL];
    } 
    [theAudio setDelegate: self];
    // loop indefinitely
    [theAudio setNumberOfLoops: -1];
    [theAudio setVolume: 1.0];
    [theAudio play];
}
```

Comment: it is telling me the stopAudio is not found

Comment: its weird the audio is still overlapping when i press multiple buttons

Comment: did you trade the code and make sure that the [theAudio stop] is called?

Comment: how do i trade the code do i have to releaser it am new to programming am still trying to learn

Answer (score 0):

The code you've posted will only play one sound, the first sound sent to the method.

If you want to only play one changeable sound, after stoping the player, release theAudio and then set the new sound.

Comment: how do i release the audio and set the new one

Answer (score 0):

In your playOnce method the 'path' variable is unused -- remove that to get rid of your warning message.  Your playOnce does not set anything up to play so I'm not sure how that is supposed to work -- unless you call playLooped first?  You also need to be calling prepareToPlay after the initWithContentsOfUrl.

```
 - (void)playOnce:(NSString *)aSound {

  NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:aSound ofType:@"caf"];
  if (theAudio && [theAudio isPlaying]) {
    [theAudio stop]
  } else {
         theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL fileURLWithPath: path] error: NULL];
         [theAudio prepareToPlay];

         [theAudio setDelegate: self];
    [theAudio setNumberOfLoops: 1];
    [theAudio setVolume: 1.0];
    [theAudio play];
  }

}
```

Comment: i deleted the playLoop line because i didn't really need it and i deleted the path line but there is still no sound playing

Comment: Add prepareToPlay, did you try that?  You do need to call the code you have in playLoop to setup the AVAudioPlayer.

Comment: i did that the sounds stop overlapping now it only plays that same sound when i try to press another button with a different sound

Comment: Ah, right, I see what you're saying.  I guess you have to check to see if you have a different sound and reload the player in that case.

Comment: i have the code for all the buttons but how do i see if i have a different sound playing and reload the player I'm new to programming so  i don't know much

Comment: You could save the aSound parameter in a class member and compare to your parameter to see if they are different.

Comment: First let me say Welcome to Stack Overflow.  The way this is meant to work is you ask a single coherent question, when you receive an answer to your question you indicate that answer by "checking" it with the check mark.  This isn't a format which is meant to be an ongoing tutorial -- you can't keep adding on to your original question.  If your one original question has not been answered yet, I'll try to help you with that.  You might want to consider reading a book on Android programming so you can learn the basics if you are just beginning -- that's what I did.

Answer (score 0):

Add a check to see if the player is already playing at the beginning of each method:

```
if (theAudio.playing == YES) {
    [theAudio stop];
}
```

[AVAudioPlayer Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios//#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to utizilize a BOOL value to get this to work properly.

in your .m file BEFORE @implementation put this:

```
static BOOL soundIsPlaying = NO;
```

Then your IBAction needs to look something like this:

```
- (IBAction)play {
    if (soundIsPlaying == YES) {
        [theAudio release];
        soundIsPlaying = NO;

    }

    else if (soundIsPlaying == NO) {
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"SOUNDFILENAME" ofType:@"wav"];
        theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
        theAudio.delegate = self;
        theAudio.volume = 1.0;
        theAudio.numberOfLoops = 0;
        [theAudio play];
        soundIsPlaying = YES;

    }   
}
```

thats honestly about it.  It will stop sounds when another button is pressed.