# iPhone sound not stopping when a second sound is played

Tags: iphone, ios4, audio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sound stop playing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8094557/sound-stop-playing)
>   [iPhone - Sound overlapping with multiple button presses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8101870/iphone-sound-overlapping-with-multiple-button-presses)

My code has sound buttons and when one is pressed it plays the sound, but when another one is pressed the sound overlaps. I have tried a few things already but nothing helps. How can I stop the sounds I'm playing from overlapping?

```
(void) playLooped: (NSString * ) aSound { 
    NSString * path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: aSound ofType: @"caf"];

    if([theAudio isPlaying])
    {
        [theAudio stop];
    }

    if (!theAudio) {
        theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL fileURLWithPath: path] error: NULL];
    } 
    [theAudio setDelegate: self];
    // loop indefinitely
    [theAudio setNumberOfLoops: -1];
    [theAudio setVolume: 1.0];
    [theAudio play];
}
```