# sound not playing when i press the button and how to fix overlapping sounds

Tags: iphone, ios4, audio, avaudioplayer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sound stop playing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8094557/sound-stop-playing)
>   [iPhone - Sound overlapping with multiple button presses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8101870/iphone-sound-overlapping-with-multiple-button-presses)

the code is giving me an error"Unused variable'path'" and when i press a button there is no sound playing how do i fix this  the aSound is in the h file

```
- (void)playOnce:(NSString *)aSound; 
- (IBAction) beatButton50 
  { 
   [self playOnce:@"racecars"];
  } 

  - (void)playOnce:(NSString *)aSound {
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:aSound ofType:@"caf"];
if([theAudio isPlaying])
{
    [theAudio stop];
}

}

- (void)playLooped:(NSString *)aSound {
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:aSound ofType:@"caf"];
if (!theAudio) {
    theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL fileURLWithPath: path] error: NULL];
} 
[theAudio setDelegate: self];
// loop indefinitely
[theAudio setNumberOfLoops: -1];
[theAudio setVolume: 1.0];
[theAudio play];
  }

- (void)stopAudio {

[theAudio stop];
[theAudio setCurrentTime:0];
   }
```